# target or targets or target's

Tags: grammaticality

in the following sentence I am not sure if I should use target, targets or target's. The sentence is for the description of an attack move of a videogame.

Here is the complete sentence:
"Water move that may hit several times and may lower its target attack stat."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use "target's" because the "'s" indicates that it is a possessive noun.

For example:
"The target's attack power."
"The cat's meow."
"The dog's blue collar."
"My aunt's boyfriend."

Target is a singular noun, whereas targets is its plural counterpart.  They are to be used when simply referred to without possession.

"The target has the attack power stat."

"The targets have increased block chance."

"The target is hard to hit."

"The targets are moving."

Here's a good resource.  https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/forming-possessive/

To also note...

"Water move that may hit several times and may lower its target attack stat."

This is stating that the water move itself has an attack stat, and that when used, it may lower the attack stat from its target amount (the amount that it wishes to have), if that makes sense.

Comment: To also note... "Water move that may hit several times and may lower its target attack stat."  This is stating that the water move itself has an attack stat, and that when used, it may lower the attack stat from its target amount (the amount that it wishes to have), if that makes sense.

Comment: That comment would be better-placed in the answer itself. On Stack Exchange, moderators sometimes delete comments without notice.

Comment: Oh - thank you!  I'll move it up there with it, I just didn't know if editing was more frowned upon than appending info in comments.  Thanks, new to Stack.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange and EL&U! Their aim is build repositories of good answers to topical questions, so they actively encourage editing by anyone to improve any question and any answer. For question-editing, the caveat is that changes should preserve the original poster's intent, and not invalidate existing answers. The trail of changes is preserved in the link "edited (how long) ago", to the left of the poster's name. Posts can even be rolled back to prior versions. So feel free to edit to improve your answers. :)

Comment: Hello Heather, Your answer was really helpful to me. I now understand the issue. The link you provided also helped a lot solidifying my understanding of the possessive noun.
Can't thank you enough :-)

Now that I better understand the possessive pronoun this is how I would write the sentence: "Water move that may hit several times and may lower the target's attack stat" (since the stat being lowered belongs to the taget)

Comment: Many thanks Lawrence, I'll keep that in mind!  You're very welcome Andre.  You've got it right now!  Good job!